# Place Div in Div with a specific margin (10px)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried do make a Webpage like this(Fullscreen):
[image]
And the color of each of them should change randomly every second.

This is the JS that I have:

```
<script>
        var tid = setInterval(chngColor, 1000);

        function chngColor() 
        {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        }
    </script>
```

Now I tried to make a fullscreen div(as big as the body) and place other divs inside the first div with the margin:10px on each side. I cant figure out the style of the divs.

```
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color="myFunction();";
        z-index: 10;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right:10px;
```

This doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean _this doesn't work_?

Comment: A single div should be enough: the gray border is the `outline` (or a solid `box-shadow`), the orange border is the actual `border` and the center is the `background-color` (with `background-clip: padding` applied)

Comment: Post the HTML code and rectify the css for better undertanding your probleme !

Comment: Can you also post HTML or create a fiddle? How are you implementing myFunction() in CSS?

Comment: Pretty sure the CSS is more or less pseudo-code.  I would imagine `background-color` just isn't set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a JavaScript function inside CSS code. What you should do instead is to use your `chngColor` function on every element that you want to change it's background.

Changing you function to take an `dom element` as a parameter

```
    function chngColor(el) 
    {
        el.style.backgroundColor = '#' + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    }
```

And supposing your elements have a common specific class, let's say "foo", you can iterate all of them and use the function for every one of them:

```
var foos = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

for(var i=0; i <foos.length;i++){
  chngColor(foos[i]);
}
```

Put that in a function so you can use in `setInterval` and you are good to go.